# Windows Powershell- Adding to a variable in a command call

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell and Stack Overflow, so sorry if this an obvious question. I have searched and searched and have not found any similar questions or answers. I am trying to call a command on Powershell and changing the file name by one. Here is the line giving me trouble:

```
fconv -rmsd ${line}_O[int]($modeO+1).mol2 --s=${line}_A$modeA.mol2
```

This program takes a line of code in the format

```
fconv -rmsd FILE_NAME.mol2 --s=FILE_NAME.mol2
```

and gives a result. My problem is adding 1 to `$modeO`. `$modeO` is a number that is pulled from a file and converted to an int by using

```
$modeO = file.txt | Select -Index 0
[int]$modeO = [convert]::ToInt32($ModeO.Trim(), 10)
```

Now, whenever I try this command it says "`could not open 5157_O6+1.mol2`" when `modeO` is 6. I want it to use the file O7, but the +1 is not adding properly. I have tried separating it with parentheses, curly braces, and putting `[int]` in front of `($modeO+1)`. Is there a way to add to a variable like this while using it? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: The code you have presented, specifically when you convert to an integer value using `[int]`, has capital M mode. Perhaps this is an issue you want to address?

Comment: No, actually that code seems to work just fine. I should probably change it just to be safe though. I've tried just typing $num=6, then the line "fconv rmsd 5157_O$num+1..." into Windows Powershell and I'm having the same problem

Comment: `$params = '-rmsd', "${line}_O$($modeO+1).mol2", "--s=${line}_A${modeA}.mol2"; & fconv @params`

Comment: Great, that's working! Thank you! Is there any way to then set the output to a new variable? Oh, never mind! I got it to work by putting $fconv= & fconv @params